# Retrieving an entity from GAE datastore by key

Tags: database, google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore

If I have the google assigned key of an entity in my datastore, say ag1iYXRjaC1nZW5lcmljchcLEgxCYXRjaGVzTW9kZWwiBUpvYiAyDA, is there a way I can easily fetch the entity by this key? I've tried using `.get_by_id()`, `.filter('__key__=', 'ag1iYXRjaC1nZW5lcmljchcLEgxCYXRjaGVzTW9kZWwiBUpvYiAyDA')` and can't seem to find anything that works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`db.get('ag1iYXRjaC1nZW5lcmljchcLEgxCYXRjaGVzTW9kZWwiBUpvYiAyDA')`